# How to figure out where canary and return address are located?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, buffer-overflow, leakcanary

I have this code gave me from my professor, he also wrote other versions of the same software going to uncomment parts of code in order to show us how a stack works but I don't really understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv);

void loop()
{
    int buf[1];
    printf("%08X %08X %08X\n", buf, loop, main);
    printf("%08X %08X %08X %08X\n", buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4]);
    printf("%08X %08X %08X %08X\n", buf[5], buf[6], buf[7], buf[8]);
    printf("loop\n");
    //buf[1] = loop;//canary alert
    //buf[2] = loop;// messes up the exit of main
    //buf[3] = 0XF0F0F0F0;
    //buf[4] = &(buf[0]);
    //buf[4] = loop;
    //buf[5] = &(buf[0]);
    //buf[5] = loop;
    printf("%08X %08X %08X %08X\n", buf[1], buf[2], buf[3], buf[4]);
    printf("%08X %08X %08X %08X\n", buf[5], buf[6], buf[7], buf[8]);
    printf("loop returns\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Main\n");
    loop();
    printf("main terminates\n");
}
```

If I uncomment buf[1] the result is "stack smashing" because I go to modify the canary. If I uncomment buf[2] I get "segmentation foult" finished executing the whole program (so I first get printf("main terminates\n"); and then the segmentation foult). If I uncomment buf[3] I get segmentation foult before the end of main execution. I think by going to uncomment buf[4] and buf[5] I am going to change the return address.
I am running this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit (The VM given by SEED https://seedsecuritylabs.org/).
My question is:
How can I know where the canary is located? Should I assume it is always in the first available position after the last variable declared and then written to the stack? How do I know, looking only at the code, where the return address can be found? I will preface this by saying that the prof has never debugged the program and so to my belief he deduced everything from the code.

Comment: Whatever course you're taking or book or tutorial you're using, it should have told you about *undefined behavior*. While all the stack manipulation in itself is UB, you seem to have forgotten (or never learned) that there are more cases of UB than just going out of bounds of arrays. For example, mismatching `printf` format specifications and argument type *also* leads to UB. Like using the `%x` format to print a pointer. To print a pointer correctly, use `%p`. And the pointer need to be casted to `void *` as well. *And* function pointers can't really be casted to `void *` anyway.

Comment: As for the stack manipulation itself, it depends on two things: The system ABI and the compiler. You need to study both in great detail. And note that stack layout may change between compiler versions even. Have you studies, read and researched all documentation needed to understand the stack layout for your system and compiler combination?

Comment: I don't know if it can be useful but I'm running SeedLabs 1.0 so an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit in a VM done with virtual box and the compiler is GCC. All the other stuff like format string vulnerability ecc. (I think you are talking about that) are other part of the course, but this C code is done in order to explain BufferOverflow